# How do i sort multidimension array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have array like

```
Array ( 
     [608665839] => Array ( [score] => 2 ) 
     [1756044141] => Array ( [score] => 5 ) 
     [523536777] => Array ( [score] => 2 ) 
)
```

and I want to sore this array by score. How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From PHP.net:

```
<?php
    function order_array_num ($array, $key, $order = "ASC")
    {
        $tmp = array();
        foreach($array as $akey => $array2)
        {
            $tmp[$akey] = $array2[$key];
        }

        if($order == "DESC")
        {arsort($tmp , SORT_NUMERIC );}
        else
        {asort($tmp , SORT_NUMERIC );}

        $tmp2 = array();       
        foreach($tmp as $key => $value)
        {
            $tmp2[$key] = $array[$key];
        }       

        return $tmp2;
    }
?>
```

$order = "ASC" will sort the array in an ascending order while $order = "DESC" will sort the array in a descending order.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

I would use [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)

Answer (score 1):

I think `[uasort()]`[1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) function is helpful for sorting this `array()`

If multiple array then use `array_[multisort()]`[2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) functions